# Javascript iterate over Unicode when Emoji has a skincolor

Tags: javascript

The problem I am facing to right now is that when there are Emojis with a different skincolor than yellow that Javascript splits it in different chars instead of one.

When I have emojis like this there is no problem an I get the results I want to have.

```js
let strs = [...""]

console.log(strs)
console.log(strs.length)
```

But if I have emojis like this there is a problem because javascript don't let me use the [...] operator with this emojis:

```js
let strs = [...""]

console.log(strs)
console.log(strs.length)
```

How can I tell Javascript that these is only one Emoji with the length of one and not two or more Emojis like in this example:

```js
let strs = [..."‍❤️‍‍"]

console.log(strs)
console.log(strs.length)
```

Comment: I googled "npm emoji split" – maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-aware might help?

Comment: There is no trivial solution. You need to parse the string and decide based on that out ow how many characters the emoji exists. So you either need to create a parser based on the specification are use a library as suggested.

Comment: Tried [emoji-aware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-aware) package mentioned by AKX above. I can confirm it works.

Comment: There’s the [RegExp set notation + properties of strings](//github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-set-notation) proposal which will make this easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) of strings (invoked via the spread syntax `...`) iterates over the code points of the string. Some emojis are made up of multiple code points which causes them to split unintentionally as you have seen. In more recent versions of lodash, you can use [`_.split()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#split) which is able to handle emojis and ZWJ characters:

```js
const r1 = _.split("‍❤️‍‍", '');
const r2 = _.split("", '');

// See browser console for output: 
console.log(r1, r1.length);
console.log(r2, r2.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Note that you don't need to include the entire lodash library to use this method, instead, you can include the method [specifically](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.split).

---

There is also a stage 4 proposal for [`Intl.Segmenter`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter), which is an API that will allow you to split/segment your string by specifying a granularity. It involves creating a *segmenter* which can split strings up based on its graphemes (ie: the visual emoji characters). When you use the segmenter on your string, you'll get an iterator, which you can then convert into an array of characters using `Array.from()`:

```js
const graphemeSplit = str => {
  const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter("en", {granularity: 'grapheme'});
  const segitr = segmenter.segment(str);
  return Array.from(segitr, ({segment}) => segment);
}
// See browser console for output
console.log(graphemeSplit("‍❤️‍‍")); // ["‍❤️‍‍"]
console.log(graphemeSplit("")); // ["", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: What a mess, thank goodness for lodash!